# Tailwind css not updating via pm2 config

Tags: node.js, tailwind-css, pm2

I'm running a nodejs Express server with PM2 and Tailwind.

When I start the app with `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js` tailwind detects template classes correctly and updates the style file.

But when I make changes to the template files, tailwind does not detect any changes (ie it doesn't seem like it's watching the files).

```
// package.json

{
  "name": "hopper",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watchcss": "npx tailwindcss -i ./public/css/tailwind.css  -o ./dist/style.css --watch",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-handlebars": "^6.0.6",
    "helmet": "^6.1.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.23",
    "mongoose-paginate-v2": "^1.7.1",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "postcss-cli-simple": "^4.0.0",
    "validator": "^13.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "postcss-cli": "^10.1.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.1"
  }
}
```

```
// ecosystem.config.json
  {
    "apps": [
      {
        "name": "TailwindCSS",
        "script": "npx tailwindcss -i ./public/css/tailwind.css  -o ./dist/style.css --watch",
        "watch": true,
        "env": {
          "NODE_ENV": "development"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "hopper",
        "script": "index.js",
        "instances": 1,
        "autorestart": true,
        "watch": true,
        "exec_mode": "fork",
        "watch_options": {
          "usePolling": true,
          "interval": 1000
        },
        "time": true,
        "env": {
          "NODE_ENV": "development"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

I'm pretty sure the tailwind config is correct as it builds the styles correctly when I run `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In any case, I managed to fix the issue by:

```
"scripts": {
  "watchcss": "npx tailwindcss -i ./public/css/tailwind.css -o ./dist/style.css --watch",
  "start": "pm2 start ecosystem.config.js",
  "dev": "concurrently \"npm run watchcss\" \"npm run start\"",
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
```

And updating the config like:

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "name": "hopper",
      "script": "index.js",
      "instances": 1,
      "autorestart": true,
      "watch": true,
      "exec_mode": "fork",
      "watch_options": {
        "usePolling": true,
        "interval": 1000
      },
      "time": true,
      "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "development"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now it works.